# Print the positive non-zero integer n-tuple(s) that solve an inequality within a bound

Tags: code-golf, math, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a linear inequality like

> x<sub>0</sub>A<sub>0</sub> + x<sub>1</sub>A<sub>1</sub> + ... + x<sub>n</sub>A<sub>n</sub> <= C

with x<sub>i</sub> a non-zero positive integer and A<sub>i</sub> and C a positive non-zero multiple of `0.01`. Find all the positive integer n-tuples {x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>} such that:

> D <= x<sub>0</sub>A<sub>0</sub> + x<sub>1</sub>A<sub>1</sub> + ... + x<sub>n</sub>A<sub>n</sub> <= C

where D is also a positive non-zero multiple of `0.01`.

---

**Challenge:** Find the shortest code to produce the n-tuple solution(s) for any A<sub>i</sub>, C, D.

---

Example: Let A<sub>0</sub>,A<sub>1</sub>=1, C = 2.5, and D=1.5. This gives

> 1.5 <= x<sub>0</sub>1+x<sub>1</sub>1 <= 2.5

Here, the (only) 2-tuple solution is {1,1}:

[image]

Comment: Why not simply multiply the equations by `100` and have everything in terms of integers ? The multiples of `0.01` don't add anything

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I think this challenge has potential but needs some clarifications. Do I understand correctly that the program takes C, D and a vector A as input and then should return all vectors X? Adding some examples and test cases would also help to understand the challenge.

Comment: Also, what are the y and z vectors?

Comment: @user202729 He means other solution tuples, they aren't extra variables

Comment: @TonHospel, you can do that.

Comment: @Laikoni, yes, exactly like you said, "the program takes C, D and a vector A as input and then should return all vectors X."

Comment: @user202729, the X,Y,...,Z vectors are the possible multiple solutions. There may be just one. There may be 187. Depends on the input, which, as mentioned above, is C, D, and a vector A.

Comment: This made enough sense to me. [link](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pzg/pyw12jEvJbpa2cZW2VhPo8y2Ijozti4kMSknta46UyekKNowTtk4tlYTKG9UW@eVn5lXF5JRlJqYEl1mZxAbq@OZV5KanlpUHKv2P6AoM68kOi3aUM9UxwiIqw11DGtjY625YBImQEEFUxABlFIAIiOQ9H8A)`TIO`

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 64 bytes

```hs
(d#c)a=[x|x<-mapM(\_->[1..c])a,y<-[sum$zipWith(*)x a],y>=d,y<=c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyNFOVkz0Ta6oqbCRjc3scBXIyZe1y7aUE8vOVYzUafSRje6uDRXpSqzIDyzJENDS7NCITFWp9LONgUoZ5sc@z83MTNPwVYhJV@BS6GgKDOvREFFQUNZU8FQz1TBGIijDXUMY/8DAA) Defines a funktion `(#)` which takes D as first argument, C as second argument and A as a list as last argument and returns a list of possible X as lists. E.g. `(#) 1.5 3.5 [1,1]` yields the three solutions `[[1.0,1.0],[1.0,2.0],[2.0,1.0]]`.

---

#### 61 bytes with D and C integers:

```hs
(d#c)a=[x|x<-mapM(\_->[1..c])a,elem(sum$zipWith(*)x a)[d..c]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyNFOVkz0Ta6oqbCRjc3scBXIyZe1y7aUE8vOVYzUSc1JzVXo7g0V6UqsyA8syRDQ0uzQiFRMzoFJB/7PzcxM0/BVqGgKDOvREFFQUNZU8FIwVQh2lDHUMco9j8A)
E.g.  `(#) 2 5 [1,1,2]` yields `[[1,1,1],[1,2,1],[2,1,1]]`.

Comment: How would you print the value that the tuples produce?

Comment: @twoblacklinesinthemiddle I miss read your question before. In the first program the resulting value for a tuple `x` is `y`, so you can return `(x,y)` instead of just `x`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcmxCsIwEADQ3a84aIc7SQJB3Jr@gbNDDHIkQoNNDbZCIv577PCmN/H6fMxzaxg6T2wsFlHpVwaZOF/wdpej1Up5RyzqIO36Sf035mvcJjxSAXaijibsZ7xrieMCBsILDpDfcdmgB@wItDrDaWe10K79AQ "Haskell – Try It Online")